# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection string. When testing Service layer with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, illegalargumentexception

Now I want to show you methods which I tried to test

```
@Service
public class AzureCloudStorageService implements FileService {
    private final String connectionString;
    private final String containerName;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

     public AzureCloudStorageService(@Autowired PropertyResolver propertyResolver,
        ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.connectionString = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.connection.string");
        this.containerName = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.container.name");
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public String upload(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        final String blob = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        BlobClient client = containerClient()
            .getBlobClient(blob + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            client.upload(new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream()), multipartFile.getSize());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new NotSavedException(ErrorMessage.FILE_NOT_SAVED);
        }
        return client.getBlobUrl();
    }

    private BlobContainerClient containerClient() {
        BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
        return serviceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    }
```

There are my poor attempt to test it, I think there is no need a lot mock I only injected Service and use it to compare with expected, in comment I wrote before what I thought I need to do

```
@InjectMocks
    AzureCloudStorageService azureCloudStorageService;

    @Test
    void upload() {
//        azureCloudStorageService.upload(multipartFile);
//        String blob = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
//        BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
//                .connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
//        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient1 = serviceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
//        BlobClient client = blobContainerClient1
//                .getBlobClient(blob + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        String expected = "image";
        MultipartFile multipartFile = ModelUtils.getFile();
        String actual = azureCloudStorageService.upload(multipartFile);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

And the last is stacktrace for my exception, I don`t know how to handle it, maybe I should mock constructor or create variables for connectionString, but I dont know how

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection string.

    at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.connectionstring.StorageConnectionString.create(StorageConnectionString.java:103)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.connectionString(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:240)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageService.containerClient(AzureCloudStorageService.java:54)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageService.upload(AzureCloudStorageService.java:42)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageServiceTest.upload(AzureCloudStorageServiceTest.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Update ----- When i debbug intelij says that in line throwing exeption

```
 .connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at `this.connectionString = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.connection.string");` and make sure your connection string is what you expect it to be

Comment: My string is null at this row

Comment: At that row yes, but if you debug one step further the `this.connectionString` should have a value set. If not, then the property "azure.connection.string" is not present in your properties

Comment: should I put it in properties for properly work?

Comment: I guess you have a properties file somewhere that the `propertyResolver` tries to get the properties out of. In this file you must have `azure.connection.string=my-connection-string`. Otherwise `propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.connection.string")` will alway return `null` or an empty string